# How I can add functionality to a jQuery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can add functionality to a jQuery method? For example, when using `hide` on an element (`<a>` or `<p>` or something else):

HTML

```
<a href="#">click me</a>
```

jQuery

```
$("a").hide()
```

I tried creating a type of plugin, but I want to keep the native functionality and then add more.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    hide: function () {
        alert("hidden element: " + $(this));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way, of course, would be to give it a different name. If you really don’t want to do that, you can keep a reference to the original method, then pass both `this` and any received arguments using `Function.prototype.apply`:

```
var originalHide = jQuery.fn.hide;

jQuery.fn.hide = function () {
    alert('hidden element: ' + this); // == $(this); neither is meaningful
    return originalHide.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: +1 for being faster than me :). I also thought about the same variable name xD

Comment: You should at least refactor to avoid introducing the `originalHide` global variable.

Comment: @plalx: Who said this was the global scope? I don’t really find the extra IIFEs necessary for short snippets…

Comment: @minitech Perhaps you don't and an experienced JS developer would understand that it's implicit here, however people asking these kind of questions aren't experienced JS developers. Therefore, I believe it's more appropriate not to infer the audience's knowledge and provide a solution which is as complete as possible.

Comment: @plalx: If the asker of a question doesn’t understand how to change scope, all the more reason not to add confusion. Globals aren’t so bad that they warrant a mention in every answer.